# Examples and Tutorial on how to use lightweight smart contracts on Ardor?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, ardor, lightweight-contracts

I've just read about Ardor's lightweight smart contracts: https://medium.com/coinmonks/lightweight-contracts-b738b6e29377

Is there an example and tutorial of how to make use of these smart contracts on Ardor? Where are they stored and how can they be accessed? What's required to get started?

Comment: this link is related https://medium.com/@lyaffe/oracle-contracts-on-ardor-94480bc4890b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightweight Contracts were released in Ardor 2.1.0e with several sample contracts. See https://nxtwiki.org/wiki/Lightweight_Contracts